# If Network Operating Systems or Virtualized Networks are installed on regular computers

Tags: sdn, virtual

I am learning about SDN and Network Operating Systems and Virtual Networks. I am confused about where the actual code that runs exists. Like when you have an application like a website, it runs on a *server* which typically is just an x86 machine with Linux installed. I'm wondering if a SDN or NOS or VN are installed at this same exact *server* layer, or if they are installed at some lower/prior layer like directly on the router. Or where they are installed.

Comment: SDN separates the control plane to a controller that instructs the network devices on what to do at the data plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions for this and no single answer.

Depending on the architecture, an SDN controller may run on a larger router, a switch, in a dedicated module or appliance, or an x86 machine, hardware or virtualized. Since there's no overall standard for SDN anything's possible.

However, there are other, more "traditional" (and simpler) ways to virtualize a network - probably the best known are VLAN (virtual L2 segment partitioning on a shared network infrastructure) and various forms of tunneling (e.g. VPN) where you create a virtual overlay network with its own topology on top of an already existing network. Even network address translation (NAT) is a form of (IP address) virtualization.